# NFC tag scanning range

Tags: wireless-networking, nfc

I've bought several NFC stickers (NTAG213) with a diameter of 25mm and build a simple scanning app for my android phone. I noticed that the tags have to be in direct contact or within a small distance (< 1cm) from the phone.

I was wondering what the actual scanning ranges are of NFC stickers and if there are NFC tags capable of transmitting data over a distance of +/- 30 centimeters. I know it all depends on the scanner hardware and size of the NFC e.g. the bigger diameter of an NFC sticker equals a bigger antenna meaning a larger range. Or do i have to switch to other tech in order to scan from 'larger' distances. My goal is to scan tags within a meter or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFC Forum standards have a range limit of 20cm, and even that is considered optimistic. You need something different.

Comment: TY Spiff, I'll  have to find another solution.